# is it possible to set BufLeave autocmd in vim on the fly?

Tags: vim, autocmd

What I want to do:

Inside a file/buffer in vim, especially an unnamed one (for example, created with :enew), sometimes I feel the content I'm writing is worth saving (say, I suddenly want to send it via an email), but don't feel the particular need to save it to a temp file, nor do I trust myself enough to "remember" to save it upon exit.

So I thought, what if I run

```
autocmd BufLeave * ggvG"+y
```

in the vim command line once and be free from the fear of losing this content.

But it doesn't work. When I exit vim, the system clipboard reminds intact.

My questions:

- does it do anything if we run `autocmd` on the fly, as opposed to in vimrc?
- is there a way to tell vim to "hey, when you exit, run these"?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1) You didn't leave the buffer to go to another buffer (`BufLeave`); you left Vim (`VimLeave`).

2) `autocmd` expects a command, not normal mode keystrokes.

With that in mind,

```
autocmd VimLeave * normal gg"+yG
```

Comment: You nailed it. In practice I'll use both `VimLeave` and `BufLeave` just to be safe. Thanks a ton!